# Determining the minimum system requirements of my application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, minimum-requirements

So, i'm about to ship out my first application, and i'd like to put the minimum and recommended system requirements. Are there any applications that can do that for me, or do i just go with the minimum system requirements of flash player?

Answer (score 0):

what kind of application you doing ? If an application for Iphone or Ipad , the minimum requirements will be determined by itunes conect.

Comment: It's a windows application. probably should have specified that in the original post. my bad